# Opening .vddproj in Visual Studio 2008 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to open a .sln file in Visual Studio 2008 Express. It prompted me an error as shown in the attached, which says that *.vddproj is not supported by this version of the application.

Is it because it cannot be opened with Express edition?

[image]

Edit 1: I opened up *.sln and took a look. It is trying to open up this "MTTS_Handy\MTTS_Handy.vddproj":

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HandyTerminal", "HandyTerminal\HandyTerminal.csproj", "{0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}"
EndProject
Project("{B900F1C2-3D47-4FEC-85B3-04AAF18C3634}") = "MTTS_Handy", "MTTS_Handy\MTTS_Handy.vddproj", "{FBE9C003-B418-4E18-84AA-A23885E7F7D7}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {0D9962DA-B521-46B6-BEC6-BFC8B7EA3E4F}.Release|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {FBE9C003-B418-4E18-84AA-A23885E7F7D7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug
        {FBE9C003-B418-4E18-84AA-A23885E7F7D7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Edit 2: I tried to open up *.vddproj, and the contents are:

> ```
> "DeployProject"
> {
> "VSVersion" = "3:701"
> "ProjectType" = "8:{AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}"
> "IsWebType" = "8:FALSE"
> "ProjectName" = "8:MTTS_Handy"
> "LanguageId" = "3:1033"
> "CodePage" = "3:1252"
> "SccProjectName" = "8:"
> "SccLocalPath" = "8:"
> "SccAuxPath" = "8:"
> "SccProvider" = "8:"
>     "Hierarchy"
>     {
>         "Entry"
>         {
>         "MsmKey" = "8:_0A93A7EC0012492D9AB60D21DBCD713F"
>         "OwnerKey" = "8:_UNDEFINED"
>         "MsmSig" = "8:_UNDEFINED"
>         }
> ```

Comment: What is vddproj. project. I think it should .vdproj.

Comment: @VinhVu I'm not too sure. I googled around and most results showed *.vdproj too. If it's *.vdproj, what's the possible causes?

Comment: I think you can try to back up your project, then change the extension of this project from .vddproj to .vdproj.

Comment: @VinhVu Tried changing the extension and reopening the solution file. It still has the same error that it is not supported by this version of the application.

Comment: I search and figure out http://extension.nirsoft.net/vddproj, may be it's about your Visual Studio 2008 Express just only support C#.

Comment: @VinhVu Sorry, but what does this mean? Because I am opening up the *.sln file in Visual Studio C# Express, that's why I am encountering this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it's a little late, this answer is more for if anyone else comes across this page via google, like i did.

.vddproj files are "Smart Device" installation packages

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8(v=vs.90).aspx

According to google, you cannot open these with Visual Studio 2008 Express. I can confirm that Visual Studio 2008 Professional does open them.
When you are installing Visual Studio, check for "Smart Device Progammability" in the features to install list.

Comment: It appears that Visual Studio 2019 can also open these once the [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) extension is installed.